# Who's the fastest runner in the DC Universe?

Tags: dc

The Flash always goes by the moniker of "*The fastest man alive*" , but there have been many villains who have shown they are faster.

So who's the definitive fastest person **in terms of running speed** in the DC Universe?

I don't care if it's a villain, a hero or an anti-hero and answers from the comics, movies or TV shows are all acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **[Wally West Flash](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flash_(Wally_West))** was ranked in first place in a list of DC's top ten speedsters published in 2018.

> 1 WALLY WEST
> "Wally understands the spiritual side of the Speed Force, and with that understanding, he trusts the Speed Force. Even though he may not fully grasp the science behind it, his faith lets Wally tap into the full breadth of the Speed Force. He doesn't run through the Speed Force, the Speed Force runs through him."
>
> [image: DC Nation Vol. 2 #2, page]
>
> <sub>*[DC Nation Vol. 2 #2](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Nation_Vol_2_2)* (September, 2018)</sub>

In an issue published in 2019, a [Watcher](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uatu_(Earth-616))-like being named [Tempus Fuginaut](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Tempus_Fuginaut_(Prime_Earth)) referred to Wally as the fastest being in the multiverse.

> TEMPUS: I--we--need the fastest being in all the multiverse... to save the worlds affected by this cataclysm... and ultimately destroy the anomaly causing it all.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Flash Forward #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flash_Forward_Vol_1_1)* (November, 2019)</sub>

Comment: How is Cheetah on that list? Not a huge DC guy but I never saw her doing anything in the realm of the others on that list.

Comment: @SDH - Per [her DC Fandom entry](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Barbara_Minerva_(New_Earth)): _Cheetah possesses greater speed than Wonder Woman, enhanced even further by training with Zoom. When Cheetah over came her psychological blocks, she managed to acquire her true speed._

Comment: Superman is much faster, but not when running.

Comment: I like how the blurb for Barry is apparently about the creator/author, and says absolutely nothing about the actual character.

Answer (score 0):

It varies depending on the writer, but the fastest person in the DC Multiverse is typically the Flash (whichever version is most prominent at the time).

Commonly there are foot races shown between Flash and Superman, with it almost always resulting in a tie.

Flash addressed this directly when he was once seeking some alone time and Superman was trying to talk to him.  Superman easily caught up to Flash and said, "Barry, come on.  We've raced before and you know I'm just as fast as you."  Barry responded with, "Those races were for charity, Clark" and sped away.

At different times, each version of the Flash has been faster than the rest.  Sometimes it's because of training, sometimes because of a better understanding of (or compatibility with) the Speed Force, sometimes it's just because they ***need*** to be faster.

**The Flash is the fastest man alive**...but which Flash currently bears that title differs.

Comment: Can you cite any specific instances where Barry Allen (Flash II) or Jay Garrick (Flash I) were stated or shown to be faster than Wally  (Flash III)?